# Rewrite rule change regex to identify different pattern in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Below rewrite configuration only redirects url of the form

/fetchHomePage.action?site=eu

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=(eu|jp|in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action$ https://example.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

What should I change in the regex above so that it can even redirect url like

/fetchHomePage.action;jsessionid=60E508BF73717B6BE0C38D80769A0A22?site=eu

Leads here are appreciated?

Comment: since you are basically copy pasting whatever query string the request sends, why don't you use [QSA] flag and get rid of the query string checking?

Comment: I need a query string check because I want to redirect only when there is one param in query string. Can you help me how can I detect ";jsessionid=60E508BF73717B6BE0C38D80769A0A22"?

Comment: alright, read my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to match a ; in the url-path.

> url-path with ";" is not matched as a query string you match it with the RewriteRule as you do with anything else.

So to match the jsessionid you just append it to the matched url-path as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=(eu|jp|in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action;jsessionid=60E508BF73717B6BE0C38D80769A0A22 https://example.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

There is no need to escape it. As for the string itself of the jsession id, you can match it however you want, like (.*)?, there may be more fitting and more specfic ways to match it but that's up to your preferences.

Comment: But there is a possibility that jsessionId is not there in the url, are you suggesting writing two rules one for jsessionId and one for without jsessionId?

Comment: Not necessary either, you can use (;jessionid=whatever)? and it will match the same uri even if jsessionid is not present. I don't think we should discuss regex here.

Comment: Can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821581/creating-variable-in-apache-config